# Drupal : “Access denied” to anonymous users on all pages

Tags: drupal, drupal-10

Since my update to Drupal 10.1.7, the entire site (page and eck) is in "Access denied" to anonymous users.

Note that it works normally when I'm connected.

I'm completely stuck!

Thanks for your help

Comment: There is no generic solution for this problem, since several contrib modules can deliver a response like this depending on their configuration. I would start by hen performing a 'drush updb', also checking php version (if compatilbe with d10), then check the contrib modules settings, check for custom patches on composer.json, check the custom modules etc...

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes its the files folder permissions where you have to set it to 755, however you can also check it with the drush login and then check in the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your responses but I found the answer!

For some reason, the "Anonymous user" role was removed during the update.

I recreated one without forgetting to give it a machine name "anonimous" and everything is back to normal!